# Occurrence of one vector in another by coordinates

Tags: java, math, vector, segment

I have 2 pair of coords: (x1;x2) - first segment and (x1'; x2') - second segment. How do I calculate the degree of occurrence of one segment in another?

Example:

vector1 - (10; 15);
vector2 - (13; 20);
vector2 is included in vector1 by 2/7.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the mathematic formala behind *f((10, 15), (13, 20)) = 2/7*? Otherwise I don't know what "degree of occurrence" is supposed to be.

Comment: i meant its for vector2 - intersection on (13; 15) and its length is 2, but i just take a decimal 2 to length of vector2, so it 2/7 @akuzminykh

Comment: maybe I put the question wrong, but I would like to calculate the length of the intersection between two segments

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: Ahh, now I get it. And you also got an answer already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If segments ends are ordered (x1 always less than x2), second segment is (x3,x4):

```
l = max(x1, x3)
r = min(x2, x4)
return l < r? (r-l)/(x4-x3): 0
```

Comment: Yes, its actually what i was looking for, thank you